# Perl global substitution of a file path

Tags: perl, file, path, substitution

I am reading a tab delimited file using Perl; and want to apply a global substitution to a file path within this file.  I have read that I need to incorporate Q and E into my substitution command; but I'm not able to get the substitution to work.  I want to replace the partial string psoft/batch/cs with ps/bat/csprd.

```
$xl[$idx] =~ s/\Qpsoft/batch/cs\E/\Q/psoft/batch/csprd\E/g;
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read about how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `\Q` to escape a delimiter. For example,

```
s/\Qa*b//
```

is equivalent to

```
s/a\*b//
```

and not

```
s/a\*b\/\/...
```

That means

```
$xl[$idx] =~ s/\Qpsoft/batch/cs\E/\Q/psoft/batch/csprd\E/g;
```

is equivalent to

```
$xl[$idx] =~ s/psoft/batch/cs <junk>
```

Solution:

```
$xl[$idx] =~ s/psoft\/batch\/cs/\/psoft\/batch\/csprd/g;
```

Better:

```
$xl[$idx] =~ s{psoft/batch/cs}{/psoft/batch/csprd}g;
```

---

### In more details

There are three steps to parsing an `m//`, `qr//` or `s///` operator.

The first step is to obtain the trailing flags that affect how the regex pattern is parsed (e.g. `x`, `s`, `m`, `i`, etc). Since Perl doesn't yet know how to parse the regex pattern and to keep costs down, Perl simply looks for the delimiter marking the end of the pattern and the end of the substitution (usually `/`), paying attention to no other character other than backslashes (`\`). `\Q` is ignored at this point.

The second step is where the double-quoted string escapes (e.g. `\Q`, `\L`, etc) and interpolation occurs. Perl won't have a regex pattern until these are processed.

Finally, Perl has a regex pattern and knows how to compile it, so the third step is to compile the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you need to use a different set of delimiters for the substitution operator.  Instead of `s///`, you can use `s{}{}`.  Another problem is that you should not use `\Q` and `\E` on the right side of `s///` because the right side is not a regular expression.  In your case, you don't need Q/E at all:

```
s{psoft/batch/cs}{/psoft/batch/csprd}g;
```

Refer to [s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Comment: Thanks everyone - I appreciate the help and the alternative code provided!